# Android Retrofit Cannot resolve symbol AuthenticationInterceptor

Tags: java, android, gradle, retrofit

I am creating a simple retrofit, but I get this error:

> Cannot resolve symbol AuthenticationInterceptor

Here:

```
public static <S> S createService(
        Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor =
                new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);

        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }
    }

    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

My build gradle Looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.keiferstone:nonet:2.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.lmntrx.livin.library.droidawesome:droid-awesome:1.1.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'me.pushy:sdk:1.0.28'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems you used [this example](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit)

In comments :

> I use retrofit 2 but AuthenticationInterceptor is in red color and when i put the cursor on i have message like Cannot resolve symbol 'AuthenticationInterceptor '

Answer :

> to be honest, the AuthenticationInterceptor is a custom Interceptor implementation. I'll update the code snippet asap to include this class.

Add this in your code, it should be ok :

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private String authToken;

    public AuthenticationInterceptor(String token) {
        this.authToken = token;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", authToken);

        Request request = builder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello I had to Change a part of your Code to this `public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {`, now I get less erros, it cannot resolve Symbol retrofit here `retrofit = builder.build();`

Comment: Thus I am using this tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/oauth-2-on-android-with-retrofit

Comment: It's defined above, in your link : `private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();`

Comment: Hi do you mind have a look at this https://kopy.io/FvNZb thats my ServiceGenerator how would that look like finally?